# SQL join issue with Laravel but id display are same

Tags: sql, laravel

I have 2 table(s) which table name is cats and products.

and I wish to join both of them and the result shown as below:
by the way the SQL I code it is

```
SELECT * 
FROM `cats` c join products p ON p.cat_id=c.id 
where c.cat_name = 'FFVII'
```

cat and products join table answer
[image]

So, here's the problem. I want the Id to show is with red color not the orange color. Is that anyway to solve this issue? Please check the image below and I will appreciate your solution. Thanks...

[final answer request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TCyk.png)

Here the function I put on the controller page

```
public function proCat(Request $request){
    $cat = $request->cat;

    $data= DB::table('products')->join('cats','cats.id','products.cat_id')
        ->where('cats.cat_name',$cat)->get();
    dd($data);
    return view('front.products',[
        'data' => $data , 'catByUser' => $cat
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't use images. Edit the question to add code as formatted text. Images are hard to read and irreproducible for those trying to help you :)

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need any fields from a table, what you can do is, mention what are the fields required in the SQL query.

So, instead of SELECT * , you have to mention fields like this,

```
SELECT cat_name, 
       p_id, 
       created_at, 
       updated_at 
FROM   cats c 
       JOIN products p 
         ON p.cat_id = c.id 
WHERE  c.cat_name = 'FFVII'
```

In your controller, You can get the result with the code below.

```
$result = DB::table('cats')
            ->join('products', 'products.cat_id', '=', 'cats_id')
            ->select('cats.cat_name', 'cats.p_id', 'cats.created_at', 'cats.updated_at', 'products.*')
            ->where('cats.cat_name', '=', 'FFVII')
            ->get();
```

Comment: yes, but I am using laravel so in the controller how should I to put the code? and I put on the function above as a reference.

Comment: Thanks. Is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: You are welcome. You can appreciate the contributor's effort by either upvoting or verifying the answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cat_name, 
       p_id, 
       cats.created_at, 
       cats.updated_at, 
       products.* 
FROM   cats c 
       JOIN products p 
         ON p.cat_id = c.id 
WHERE  c.cat_name = 'FFVII'
```